# What does Range.HorizontalAlignment = 1 mean in excel

Tags: vba, excel, alignment, range

I try to get sheet format in VBA, I found there is default value for HorizontalAlignment is equal to 1, but there is no this value in MSND, here are possible values, does anyone help me?

```
xlCenter = -4108
xlDistributed = -4117
xlJustify = -4130
xlLeft = -4131
xlRight = -4152
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Const xlHAlignGeneral = 1
```

You're looking at the wrong enum. Look into [`XlHAlign`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241313(v=office.12).aspx):

- xlHAlignCenter: -4108
- xlHAlignCenterAcrossSelection: 7
- xlHAlignDistributed: -4117
- xlHAlighFill: 5
- xlHAlighGeneral: 1
- xlHAlignJustify: -4130
- xlHAlignLeft: -4131
- xlHAlignRight: -4152

There's also a `XlVAlign` enum, for vertical alignment. You can find it (and everything else) in the *Object Browser* (F2):

[image]

Seems the `xlCenter` you're using is defined in the `Excel.Constants` enum. `XlHAlign` and `XlVAlign` enum values are likely just aliases for them.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I want to know. In fact, I want to get standard HorizontalAlignment for sheet, like `Application.ActiveSheet.StandardHeight, Application.ActiveSheet.StandardWidth, Application.StandardFontSize, Application.StandardFont`, which object can I use to  get it?

Comment: Default would be `xlHAlignGeneral`

Comment: Can you me which property? Property name?

Comment: It's a property of the `Range` class. `Range.HorizontalAligmnent`. I don't understand what you're asking. Grab any cell you haven't touched, its properties are all the defaults.

Comment: I tried to convert a format sheet to vbScript, I want to get the sheet default alignment, code like `sLines = sLines & ".Cells.HorizontalAlignment = " & Cells.HorizontalAlignment & vbCrLf`, but `Cells.HorizontalAlignment ` is blank, so I want to know which property is default sheet alignment...

Comment: @mikezang I don't know what `.Cells` is referring to, but `.Cells` is completely redundant and useless in `?Range("A1").Cells.HorizontalAlignment`. Both that and `Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment` print `1` to the debug/immediate pane, as does `Cells.HorizontalAlignment`. If you have problem X, don't ask a question about problem Y... If there is no `StandardEverything` property in the object model - you can hit F2 and browse the Excel object model yourself if you try! ...assuming we're still talking about VBA, which isn't VBScript at all...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161778/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-mikezang).